# Python datetime module current time in HR:MIN:SEC

Tags: python, time

It seems like i should be able to find some sort of documentation on this, but everything im finding isnt working. In Python (v. 3.3) how do you get the current time in HR:MIN:SEC format using the datetime module?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Other units of time can be found by using the directives [found here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).