# How can you update local time from the datetime module?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that uses a while loop to check if it is a certain time, and if it is that certain time, it prints a statement. I have all the if-statements set up, but the time does not update once the program starts (if I start the program at 6 pm, it will always output 6 pm for local time). Is there a way to update the time within the while loop?

I tried to research some additional functions/methods to datetime, but from what I have seen, I have not been able to find any that updates the time while the program is running. Additionally, forums regarding datetime and locale time that I have found on stackoverflow are commonly ones that just explain how to obtain the locale time once (ex, [Python datetime module current time in HR:MIN:SEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285964/python-datetime-module-current-time-in-hrminsec)). Other forums regarding locale times that I have found also tended to be in different languages, particularly C# and PHP. Please correct me if there is another forum that answers my question!

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime
import time
import webbrowser

now = datetime.now()
sleep = False
today = date.today()
roundCheck = 0
print("Awaiting time check...")

while sleep != True:
    print('Up here...')
    if roundCheck != 0:
        print('Stuck in time...')
        time.sleep(60)
    print('Time is done')
    if str(now.strftime('%H')) == '20' and str(now.strftime('%M')) == '05':
        print('Now the while loop will end')
        sleep = True
    roundCheck = 1
    print('Another round has passed')

print('Outside while loop')
```

When the time is 20:05, sleep should be set to true and the print statement outside the while loop can be executed. However, when I start the program at an earlier time (20:00, for example), it only uses that time for checking now.strftime().

Comment: For future questions, you need to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`now` never changes. You simply need to put `now = datetime.now()` in the while loop.